# Matching variable-term equations

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to develop a regular expression to match the following equations:

```
(Price+10%+100+200)
(Price+20%+200)
(Price+30%)
(Price+100)

(Price-10%-100-200)
(Price-20%-200)
(Price-30%)
(Price-100)
```

My regex so far is...

```
/([(])+([P])+([r])+([i])+([c])+([e])+([+]|[-]){1}([\d])+([+]|[-])?([\d])+([%])?([)])/g
```

..., but it only matches the following equations:

```
(Price+100+10%)
(Price+100+100)
(Price+200)
(Price-100-10%)
(Price-100-100)
(Price-200)
```

Can someone help me understand how to make my pattern match the full set of equations provided?

Note: Parentheses and 'Price' are musts in the equations that the pattern must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which matches all the input strings provided in the question:

```
/\(Price([+-]\d+%?){1,3}\)/g
```

You can test it in a [regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/x1yaq).

Things to note:

- Only use parentheses where you want to group.  Parentheses around single-possibility, fixed-quantity matches (e.g. `([P])` provide no value.
- Use character classes (opened with `[` and closed with `]`) for *multiple* characters that can match at a position in the pattern (e.g. `[+-]`).  Single-possibility character classes (e.g. `[P]`) similarly provide no value.
- Yes, character classes (generally) implicitly escape regex special characters within them (e.g. `(` in `[(]` vs. equivalent `\(` outside a character class), but to *just* escape regex special characters (i.e. to match them literally), you are better off not using a character class and just escaping them (e.g. `\(`) – unless multiple characters should match at a position in the pattern (per the previous point to note).
- The quantifier `{1}` is (almost) always useless: drop it.
- The quantifier `+` means "one or more" as you probably know.  However, in a series of cases where you used it (i.e. `([(])+([P])+([r])+([i])+([c])+([e])+`), it would match many values that I doubt you expect (e.g. `((((((PPPrriiiicccceeeeee`): basically, don't overuse it.  Stop to consider whether you really want to match one *or more* of the character (class) or group to which `+` applies in the pattern.
- To match a literal string without any regex special characters like `Price`, just use the literal string at the appropriate position in the pattern – e.g. `Price` in `\(Price`.

Comment: @AmukSaxena: Glad to hear it. I added a few notes you may want to consider based on my read of the pattern with which you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was about to ask questions based on my regex. I am very happy to read your notes. Now next time I would keep in mind before making regex

Answer (score 1):

`/\(Price[+-](\d)+(%)?([+-]\d+%?)?([+-]\d+%?)?\)/g`

works on http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[(Price]+\d+\d+([%]|[)])&/i
```

try at your own risk!